# Converting values of inputs into variables

Tags: javascript, html, forms

I want to convert values written by a user into a button modelized as following

```
process.php?fname=$fname&lname=$lname
```

I wroe the following code

```
<form id="identification" action="/action_page.php">
  First name: <input type="text" name="fname" value="Mickey"><br>
  Last name: <input type="text" name="lname" value="Mouse"><br><br>
</form> 

<button onclick="getName()">Try it</button>

<p id="result"></p>

<script>
function getName() {
    var x = document.getElementById("identification");
    var text = "";
    var i;
    for (i = 0; i < x.length ;i++) {
        text += x.elements[i].value + "<br>";
    }
    document.getElementById("result").innerHTML = text;
}
</script>
```

My question is how to convert the given into a button that will show a button redirecting to the webpage with fname and lname varianles

Answer (score 0):

Here you go

```js
function getName() {
    var x = document.getElementById("identification");
    var text = "process.php?";
    var i;
    for (i = 0; i < x.length ;i++) {
        text += x.elements[i].name + '=' + x.elements[i].value;
        if(i < x.length - 1) {
            text += '&';
        }
    }
    document.getElementById("result").innerHTML = '<a href="' + text + '"><button>LINK</button></a>';
}
```

```html
<form id="identification" action="/action_page.php">
  First name: <input type="text" name="fname" value="Mickey"><br>
  Last name: <input type="text" name="lname" value="Mouse"><br><br>
</form> 

<button onclick="getName()">Try it</button>

<p id="result"></p>
```

Comment: You should call `encodeURIComponent()` in case the input contains special characters.

Comment: And what for dropdown elements ?

Comment: @RichadAson dropdown elements have `value` property too, see example here: https://www.w3schools.com/jsref/tryit.asp?filename=tryjsref_select_value

Answer (score 0):

I would question your approach to this form at all, but here's a simple and clean solution:

```
function getName() {
    var inputs = document.querySelectorAll('#identification input[type="text"]');
    var params = [];
    var url = '/process.php?';

    // Map array of text inputs from the form into an array of name=value strings
    params = [...inputs].map(i => `${i.name}=${i.value}`)
    // Join the array with & and add it to the url string
    url += encodeURI(params.join('&'))

    // window.location = url
    document.querySelector('#result').textContent = url
}
```

[JSFiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/AndyCormack/stwa3bL8/28/)